# Difference between *(x+4) and (x+4)

Tags: c

Given:

```
 int x[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

What's the difference between:
`*(x+4)` and `(x+4)` ??

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking because `*(x + 4)` and `(x + 4)` are completely different. What is confusing you?

Comment: @iharob, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Please post a use case and I will tell you the difference, as they appear in your question you can't compare them.

Comment: `x+4` is a pointer, and `*(x+4)` is the value pointed to by that pointer, or `x[4]`. Just seeing the `*` symbol woult tell they're very different.

Comment: Given `int y = 5;` what's the difference between `(y + 3) / 4` and `(y + 3)`?

Answer (score 1):

`*(x + 4)` dereferences the fifth element of the array, which has value `4`.

`(x + 4)` is the address of the fifth element of the array (which is the corresponding address of the value `4`).

You can check what `(x + 4)` is, and why:

```
printf( "sizeof( int ) = %ld \n", sizeof( int ) );
printf( "x = %p \n", x );
printf( "(x + 4) = %p \n", (x + 4));
```

Sample output:

```
sizeof( int ) = 4 
x = 0x7fff3c0e5fc0         # address of the first element
(x + 4) = 0x7fff3c0e5fd0   # address of the fifth element
```

Comment: This is ok, but the question is weird. I wanted to understand why the OP is asking this.

Comment: yeah, just give him what he asked for